# Auto Update multiple web pages instance in Angular

Tags: php, angular, api, auto-update

I'm working on Angular website and PHP API,

I intend to auto update all the opened Angular websites with new data.

E.g. The website is open in multiple devices and if one user modifies the data the same should be updated automatically in all users screen without manual reload, Like live scoring in the matches happens.

Please suggest how can I achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

There are several approaches to this:

1. You can use ajax that always request a server for an update. Here you can use Interval.
2. [Use google firebase notification](https://firebase.google.com/?gclid=EAIaIQobChMIvseu78yj6gIVxxsYCh2U-gdtEAAYASAAEgL-UPD_BwE)
3. [Php Package for notification](https://packagist.org/packages/minishlink/web-push)

> Note that 1st one can solve the problem but it's not a good approach. It's mainly task of socket programming.

Answer (score 0):

This could be achieve in many ways.

## Websockets

[Websockets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) are duplex channels, using an opened connection. Basically the browsers of the users and the server will act as if they were computers in a network, communicating with [sockets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_socket), hence the naming. No page reloads are needed and the messages arrive at the speed the network is able to bring them to the target.

[Rachet](http://socketo.me/) is a PHP-based WebSocket support. You might want to look into that.

## Push notifications

This approach would be sending the change request from the client-side and then the server would process it and send push notification to other sessions.

Example: https://github.com/web-push-libs/web-push-php

## Polling

The separate browser tabs/browsers could repeatedly send requests to the server to see whether there are any news and if so, to act accordingly. However, [polling](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/polling-in-javascript-ab2d6378705a) is a form of [busy-waiting](https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/what-is-busy-wait).

## Forever frame

A forever frame is an `iframe` which loads forever, hence the connection is always open and the server is able to send messages to the browser, see [this](https://www.etsy.com/market/forever_frame).

It's an ugly hack if you ask me, which was needed historically, in the past, because Websockets and push notifications were not available, yet their benefits were needed. It's interesting to note forever frames as something interesting and witty, but I would not advise its use.